# errors always appeared when I install new packages in Ubuntu

Tags: apt

When I use this command `sudo apt-get install ***` to install new packages in my ubuntu, but mysql always report this error, is there any people can help me resolve this problems, thanks very much.

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 86 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.23-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
/var/lib/mysql/ibdata1:  6982
ERROR: Database files are locked. Daemon already running?
Warning: Unable to start the server. Please restart MySQL and run mysql_upgrade to ensure the database is ready for use.
/var/lib/mysql/ibdata1:  6982
ERROR: Database files are locked. Daemon already running?
Warning: Unable to start the server.
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2018-10-11 17:12:54 CST; 14ms ago
  Process: 30930 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 30921 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1090 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-5.7 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

[the information is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bah9w.png)

Comment: Did you follow the advice ? `Please restart MySQL and run mysql_upgrade to ensure the database is ready for use.`

Comment: Also this might be a good hint: `ERROR: Database files are locked. Daemon already running?`

Comment: Thanks, I have already reinstalled mysql